# TabLayout do app não aparece quando opera em Mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Estou criando um app que possui uma TabLayout com três Tabs que devem retornar Fragmentos específicos cada. No entanto, quando testo o app no mobile nenhuma das tabs é apresentada, o que impossibilita fazer qualquer coisa. Segue o layout da activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_timeline" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_graph" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_ll_settings" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dip"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a Main Activity:

```
package com.example.mastiffcollar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import com.example.mastiffcollar.contents.ActivityReport;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.contents.ContentObject;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.fragments.GraphFragment;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.fragments.IFragmentListener;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.fragments.LLFragmentAdapter;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.fragments.TimelineFragment;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.service.RetroBandService;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.utils.AppSettings;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.utils.Constants;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.utils.Logs;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.utils.RecycleUtils;
import com.example.mastiffcollar.utils.Utils;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, IFragmentListener {

// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "RetroWatchActivity";

// Context, System
private Context mContext;
private RetroBandService mService;
private Utils mUtils;
private ActivityHandler mActivityHandler;

// Global

// UI stuff
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private LLFragmentAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;

private ImageView mImageBT = null;
private TextView mTextStatus = null;

// Refresh timer
private Timer mRefreshTimer = null;



/*****************************************************
 *   Overrided methods
 ******************************************************/

@Override
public void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //----- System, Context
    mContext = this;//.getApplicationContext();
    mActivityHandler = new ActivityHandler();
    AppSettings.initializeAppSettings(mContext);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Load static utilities
    mUtils = new Utils((MainActivity) mContext);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the primary sections of the app.
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new LLFragmentAdapter(mFragmentManager, mContext, this, mActivityHandler);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    // Setup views
    //mImageBT = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.status_title);
    mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_invisible));
    //mTextStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_init));

    // Do data initialization after service started and binded
    doStartService();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // Stop the timer
    if(mRefreshTimer != null) {
        mRefreshTimer.cancel();
        mRefreshTimer = null;
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    finalizeActivity();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory (){
    super.onLowMemory();
    // onDestroy is not always called when applications are finished by Android system.
    finalizeActivity();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_scan:
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            doScan();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_discoverable:
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();      // TODO: Disable this line to run below code
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    // This prevents reload after configuration changes
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Implements TabListener
 */
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void OnFragmentCallback(int msgType, int arg0, int arg1, String arg2, String arg3, Object arg4) {
    switch(msgType) {
        case IFragmentListener.CALLBACK_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND:
            if(mService != null)
                mService.startServiceMonitoring();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


/*****************************************************
 *  Private methods
 ******************************************************/

/**
 * Service connection
 */
private ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity - Service connected");

        mService = ((RetroBandService.LLServiceBinder) binder).getService();

        // Activity couldn't work with mService until connections are made
        // So initialize parameters and settings here, not while running onCreate()
        initialize();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

/**
 * Start service if it's not running
 */
private void doStartService() {
    Log.d(TAG, "# Activity - doStartService()");
    startService(new Intent(this, RetroBandService.class));
    bindService(new Intent(this, RetroBandService.class), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

/**
 * Stop the service
 */
private void doStopService() {
    Log.d(TAG, "# Activity - doStopService()");
    mService.finalizeService();
    stopService(new Intent(this, RetroBandService.class));
}

/**
 * Initialization / Finalization
 */
private void initialize() {
    Logs.d(TAG, "# Activity - initialize()");
    mService.setupService(mActivityHandler);

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // RetroWatchService.setupBT() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if(!mService.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    // Load activity reports and display
    if(mRefreshTimer != null) {
        mRefreshTimer.cancel();
    }

    // Use below timer if you want scheduled job
    //mRefreshTimer = new Timer();
    //mRefreshTimer.schedule(new RefreshTimerTask(), 5*1000);
}

private void finalizeActivity() {
    Logs.d(TAG, "# Activity - finalizeActivity()");

    if(!AppSettings.getBgService()) {
        doStopService();
    } else {
    }

    // Clean used resources
    RecycleUtils.recursiveRecycle(getWindow().getDecorView());
    System.gc();
}

/**
 * Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
 */
private void doScan() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
}

/**
 * Ensure this device is discoverable by others
 */
private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if (mService.getBluetoothScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


/*****************************************************
 *  Public classes
 ******************************************************/

/**
 * Receives result from external activity
 */
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Logs.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case Constants.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                if(address != null && mService != null)
                    mService.connectDevice(address);
            }
            break;

        case Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a BT session
                mService.setupBT();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                Logs.e(TAG, "BT is not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }   // End of switch(requestCode)
}



/*****************************************************
 *  Handler, Callback, Sub-classes
 ******************************************************/

public class ActivityHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch(msg.what) {
            // BT state messages
            case Constants.MESSAGE_BT_STATE_INITIALIZED:
                mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_title) + ": " +
                        getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_init));
                mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_invisible));
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_BT_STATE_LISTENING:
                mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_title) + ": " +
                        getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_wait));
                mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_invisible));
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_BT_STATE_CONNECTING:
                mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_title) + ": " +
                        getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_connect));
                mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_away));
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_BT_STATE_CONNECTED:
                if(mService != null) {
                    String deviceName = mService.getDeviceName();
                    if(deviceName != null) {
                        mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_title) + ": " +
                                getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_connected) + " " + deviceName);
                        mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_online));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_BT_STATE_ERROR:
                mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_state_error));
                mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_busy));
                break;

            // BT Command status
            case Constants.MESSAGE_CMD_ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED:
                mTextStatus.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_cmd_sending_error));
                mImageBT.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_busy));
                break;

            ////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Contents changed
            ////////////////////////////////////////////
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ_ACCEL_REPORT:
                ActivityReport ar = (ActivityReport)msg.obj;
                if(ar != null) {
                    TimelineFragment frg = (TimelineFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(LLFragmentAdapter.FRAGMENT_POS_TIMELINE);
                    frg.showActivityReport(ar);
                }
                break;

            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ_ACCEL_DATA:
                ContentObject co = (ContentObject)msg.obj;
                if(co != null) {
                    GraphFragment frg = (GraphFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(LLFragmentAdapter.FRAGMENT_POS_GRAPH);
                    frg.drawAccelData(co.mAccelData);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}   // End of class ActivityHandler

/**
 * Auto-refresh Timer
 */
private class RefreshTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public RefreshTimerTask() {}

    public void run() {
        mActivityHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO:
                mRefreshTimer = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

E isso é tudo o que aparece quando o aplicativo está operando no aparelho mobile:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que o `ViewPager` está sobrepondo o `TabLayout`. Para corrigir isso, crie um novo layout chamado `content_main.xml` e inclua-o no `activity_main.xml`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_timeline" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_graph" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_ll_settings" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="content_main.xml"/>
```

No `content_main.xml` inclua o ViewPager.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Isso é o suficiente pra corrigir o problema da sobreposição. Ou simplesmente adicione um `marginTop` de aproximadamente `110dp` do `ViewPager`, mas não é uma prática recomendada. Também notei que você incluiu outro elemento dentro no `ViewPager`, e isso não faz sentido. Então deixe-o vazio.

O layout `activity_main.xml` precisa ficar dentro de um `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Eu testei isso mas ainda não funcionou, existe algo muito específico impedindo que o ViewPager seja apresentado pela Main Activity.